# Eclipse PyDev - Python stops when trying to run in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, pydev

After upgrading to Python 3.6, Eclipse debug mode stopped working properly. It renders an error like this:[image]

The strangest thing is that this issue does not raise in 100% of cases. Sometimes it goes away. And then again arises. I am lost trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Although it happens when you're running the PyDev debugger, the debugger is probably only exercising some path in your code which has a bug and is usually not exercised (and thus leads to such an error).

In this case, attach a c/c++ debugger to the program to find the culprit (you can use the attach to after that error is hit)... On Windows you can use Visual C++ and on Linux GDB.

-- as a note, the issue is **probably** on some c/c++ library you're using (but given the info, it's really hard to pinpoint anything).